# How to modify Axes Style/Ticks of RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting

Could one modify the output of the following

```
  z1 = RegionPlot[ p > Sin[q], {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Brown,
    AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}];
z2 = RegionPlot[ (p > Sin[q^2]), {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Gray, AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}];
Show[z2, z1 ]
```

to something like this:

[image]

with preferably *arrow heads* at the end of axes? The marks on horizontal and vertical axes are where I want to write $\beta$ and $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

```
Clear[z1, z2];
z1 = RegionPlot[p > Sin[q], {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Brown, 
   AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}, BoundaryStyle -> None];
z2 = RegionPlot[(p > Sin[q^2]), {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Gray, AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}, 
   Ticks -> {{{1.5, Style[α, 16]}}, {{1, Style[β, 16]}}},
    Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.05}}], 
   PlotRangePadding -> .2, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[z2, z1]
```

[image]

```
FrameTicks -> {{{{1.5, α}}, None}, {{{1, β}}, None}}
```

```
z1 = RegionPlot[p > Sin[q], {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Brown, 
   AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}];
z2 = RegionPlot[(p > Sin[q^2]), {p, 0, 2}, {q, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Gray, AxesLabel -> {"S", "T"}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{{1.5, Style[α, 16]}}, 
      None}, {{{1, Style[β, 16]}}, None}}];
Show[z2, z1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @cvgmt. I was wondering if it is possible to have this plot without Frame, just two axes with arrow heads.

Comment: Thanks, @cvgmt. How to get ride of that bluish borderline ?

Comment: @Mike `BoundaryStyle -> None`.